# How to add an items per page drop down menu to index view in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a paginated index view in Rails 3.2 with a drop down menu to select the number of items displayed per page.  I am using the will_paginate gem and the pagination function is working great.

However, with my current setup shown below, I am getting validation errors when changing the drop down menu selection.  It appears to be trying to create or save a Contact model instead of just making another request to the index action. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my index action:

```
def index
  #logic here to set per_page value depending on request?
  @contacts = Contact.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

Here is my index.html.erb view with my attempt at a drop down menu for items per page:

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => "index", :method => "get" }, { :id => "contacts-index" }) do %>
  <%= select_tag(:view, options_for_select([["10", 10], ["25", 25], ["50", 50]]), { :id => "switch-view" }) %>
<% end %>

<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact.first_name %><%= contact.last_name %>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, here is the jQuery I am using to try to submit the new request to contacts#index  when the items per page is changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#switch-view").change(function() {
    $("#contacts-index").submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:method => get` should be moved out of the first hash.

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => "index"}, { :method => "get", :id => "contacts-index" }) do %>
```

Without this, it's doing a post and submitting the 'method' as a param.  A post to the 'index' url will result in the validation errors you're seeing.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!  After a new request, the url shows some weird parameters: localhost:3000/contacts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&view=25.  Is that normal?

Comment: You can get rid of the utf8 in various ways.  You can either just render a form (not a form tag).  Or, sincey you're running jQUery, you can do something like this:  $('form[method=get] input[name=utf8]').attr("disabled", "disabled");  I end up putting this on the bottom of my layout and doing it for all get forms.

Comment: That worked too.  I used a plain old html form tag.  Thank you.